# How do you create inputs for custom options in the Magento admin

Tags: magento

I've created a new custom option type and inserted it into the Magento back end.  I've got the front end portion of this working rather nicely.  However, I can't figure out how to customize the interface for the new option type.

To be more specific as to what I am doing, I created non-displayed categories that contain products which represent options. I did this so I could use the excellent image resources Magento's products have.  I have a nice little lightbox displaying these options, and it updates the form fields as required.

What I need is a way to select the base level category that the lightbox will display using a drop down.  Right now the default "text" form shows up, but only after I save the product, prior to that it shows an empty div.

Does anyone know how I can get code for a custom input to display?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you've written to create the custom option & save its value?

Comment: Well... so far I'm into about 12 files including xml files, phtml files, model classes and block classes.  There is a brick ton of relevant code here.  If you don't know already know how to do this, I doubt code snippets will be overly helpful.  What I will do is provide the files I've been working with so you can let me know if there is some other place I need to go.  See edits above.